# android.net.uri getQueryParameterNames() alternative

Tags: android, api, parameters, uri

I'm looking for an alternative way to get the query parameter names from an android.net.Uri. getQueryParameterNames() require api level 11. I'd like to do the same for any lower level api. 
I was looking at getQuery() which will return everything after the '?' sign. Would the best way to go about this be to parse that string and search for everything before an '=' and capture that? I simply do not know what query parameters will be presented every time.

Comment: Should be some simple string parsing, give me a few minutes and I'll have a function up for you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only problem with APIs < 11 is that this method is not implemented. I guess the best idea is to look into Android source code and use implementation from API >= 11. This should get you absolutely identic functionality even on older APIs.

This one is from 4.1.1, modified to take Uri as a parameter, so you can use it right away:

```
/**
 * Returns a set of the unique names of all query parameters. Iterating
 * over the set will return the names in order of their first occurrence.
 *
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if this isn't a hierarchical URI
 *
 * @return a set of decoded names
 */
private Set<String> getQueryParameterNames(Uri uri) {
    if (uri.isOpaque()) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This isn't a hierarchical URI.");
    }

    String query = uri.getEncodedQuery();
    if (query == null) {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }

    Set<String> names = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    int start = 0;
    do {
        int next = query.indexOf('&', start);
        int end = (next == -1) ? query.length() : next;

        int separator = query.indexOf('=', start);
        if (separator > end || separator == -1) {
            separator = end;
        }

        String name = query.substring(start, separator);
        names.add(Uri.decode(name));

        // Move start to end of name.
        start = end + 1;
    } while (start < query.length());

    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(names);
}
```

If you want to dig into it yourself, here is the original code:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/net/Uri.java?av=f

Comment: I'm puzzled by this code, and I suspect it's because I'm using a newer version of the Android SDK (API 18). The query variable is populated from uri.getEncodedQuery(), which -- based on my testing -- encodes all of the & characters. As a result of using the encoded string, the call to indexOf() always returns -1, and the entire query string is returned, as if it were a parameter name.

Comment: Here is [implementation from Android 4.4.2](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/net/Uri.java#Uri.getQueryParameterNames%28%29) and it is the same. You are probably using `Uri.Builder.query(String)`, which will encode the whole parameter even with `&` and `=`. You should use `Uri.Builder.appendQueryParameter(String, String)` which encodes the parameter names and values, but keeps separators intact. When you call `Uri.getEncodedQuery()`, it returns this query with parameter names and values encoded but `&` and `=` intact.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a `java.net.URI` (or create one), you can use `URLEncodedUtils.parse` to get the parameters and values as `NameValuePair`:

```
Map<String, String> parameters = Maps.newHashMap();
List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(uri, "UTF-8");
for (NameValuePair param : params) {
    parameters.put(param.getName(), param.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Definitely the cleanest of all the solutions proposed so far!

Comment: Note: that's org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils, just to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with foxter that the best choice is to get the code from the newest Android version and add to your codebase. Everytime I'm faced with issues like this, I create a method to abstract versions idiosyncrasies. It goes like this:

```
public class FWCompat {
    public static boolean isFroyo_8_OrNewer() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO;
    }
    public static boolean isGingerbread_9_OrNewer() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD;
    }
    public static boolean isHoneycomb_11_OrNewer() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
    }
    public static boolean isHoneycomb_13_OrNewer() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2;
    }
    public static boolean isJellyBean_16_OrNewer() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN;
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class FWUriCompat {

    public static Set<String> getQueryParameterNames(Uri uri) {
        if (FWCompat.isHoneycomb_11_OrNewer()) {
            return uri.getQueryParameterNames();
        }

        return FW_getQueryParameterNames(uri);
    }

    private static Set<String> FW_getQueryParameterNames(Uri uri) {
        if (uri == null) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Can't get parameter from a null Uri");
        }

        if (uri.isOpaque()) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This isn't a hierarchical URI.");
        }

        String query = uri.getEncodedQuery();
        if (query == null) {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }

        Set<String> names = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        int start = 0;
        do {
            int next = query.indexOf('&', start);
            int end = (next == -1) ? query.length() : next;

            int separator = query.indexOf('=', start);
            if (separator > end || separator == -1) {
                separator = end;
            }

            String name = query.substring(start, separator);
            names.add(Uri.decode(name));

            // Move start to end of name.
            start = end + 1;
        } while (start < query.length());

        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(names);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok well here's what I've came up with. Haven't compiled or tested it so no guarantees here

```
ArrayList<String> getQueryParamNames(String input) 
{
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    //If its everything after the ? then up to the first = is the first parameter
    int start = 0;
    int end = input.indexOf("=");

    if (end == -1) return null; //No parameters in string

    while (end != -1)
    {
        result.Add(input.substring(start, end)); //May need to do end - 1 to remove the =
        //Look for next parameter, again may need to add 1 to this result to get rid of the &
        start = input.indexOf("&", end); 
        if (start == -1) //No more parameters
            break;

        //If you want to grab the values you can do so here by doing
        //input.substring(end, start);

        end = input.indexOf("=", start);
    }
    return result;  
}
```

I wrote this late at night, without testing it, so you might have to adjust some of the calls by adding or subtracting 1. Also I may have forgotten the exact syntax for adding to a `List`. I guess comment on any errors for others to see but this is the general gist of it. I have a feeling I forgot a `;` somewhere.

EDIT: Set result to a new ArrayList instead of LinkList as suggested below

Comment: ArrayList<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();
is not the best idea

Comment: @paiNie You're right, I've changed my answer to just create a new ArrayList instead of LinkList.